# call async action from another controllers' synchronous action

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Imagine we have asynchronous action defined in controller:

```
public class PortalController : AsyncController {
public void NewsAsync(string city) {

    AsyncManager.OutstandingOperations.Increment();
    NewsService newsService = new NewsService();
    newsService.GetHeadlinesCompleted += (sender, e) =>
    {
        AsyncManager.Parameters["headlines"] = e.Value;
        AsyncManager.OutstandingOperations.Decrement();
    };
    newsService.GetHeadlinesAsync(city);
}

public ActionResult NewsCompleted(string[] headlines) {
    return View("News", new ViewStringModel
    {
        NewsHeadlines = headlines
    });
}
```

When I call it from browser - everything works. But I want to call this action (News) from another synchronous controller. Is there any way to call action and get the result?

Answer (score 0):

```
public class PortalController: Controller {
    public ActionResult News(string city) {
        NewsService newsService = new NewsService();
        ViewStringModel headlines = newsService.GetHeadlines(city);
        return View(headlines);
    }
}
```

you should have looked at the rest of the [code you got From MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee728598%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) you can't have a view without an ActionResult of some sort to get the data.

Comment: This way the call is synchronous and blocks the main thread. I have mentioned I want the action to be asynchronous. Anyway I managed to do that by having action to return `Task<ActionResult>` not just void.

Comment: I apologize, I didn't understand your question fully.  So were you able to update the code to return a result instead of a void function?